# Hide last child if there are more than 3 children

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to hide last td if there are more than 3 td's in a row. Something doesn't work

Here is jquery code

```
      if (screen.width < 320) {
        $(".slider-navigation-thumbs table tr").each(function(){
           var tdsnumber = $(this).children().length;
          if (tdsnumber > 3) {
            $(this).child().last().hide();
          } 
        });
      }
```

**Additional info**
For experiment sake, removed the screen size reading part. works fine without it. So, i'm guessing mistake is somewhere there, but can't figure out what's wrong. Tried increasing 320 to 340, but still no go.

Comment: Wait, is your problem related to "hiding last child" or the condition that's surrounding it? Btw, unless you're doing something magical `jQuery.fn.child` doesn't exist so it shouldn't "work fine".

Answer (score 2):

There is no `child()` method. You probably want `children()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.children().length` but then later you're using `.child()`; that's obviously wrong.

That said, here's something simpler:

```
$(".slider-navigation-thumbs table tr > td:gt(2):last").hide();
```

It selects the children inside `<tr>` that have a higher index than 2 (meaning the fourth child onwards), then selects the last element of that set; finally, it hides the resulting element.

If there are only three child elements, it will return an empty set and thus nothing gets hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `.child()`with `.find('td')` or `.children()`:

```
if (screen.width < 320) {
    $(".slider-navigation-thumbs table tr").each(function(){
       var tdsnumber = $(this).children().length;
      if (tdsnumber > 3) {
        $(this).find('td').last().hide();
      } 
    });
  }
```

Comment: added some extra info

Comment: i am sure that `screen.width < 320` is not getting satisfied here. try alerting the value `screen.width`

Comment: i've tried a width of 2300, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.child()` method,

```
if (screen.width < 320) {
    $(".slider-navigation-thumbs table tr").filter(function(){
        return  $(this).children().length > 3
    }).children('td:last-child').hide()
}
```

Comment: @whatzi77 can you share the html sample

Comment: added some extra info

Comment: @whatzi77 whether your code is in a window resize handler... if not move it to `$(window).resize(function(){...})`